# question id is not changing for user_choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my
**question.controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @questions = Question.all
     end

      def new
         @question=Question.new 
        end
        def create
            @question=Question.new(question_params)
            if @question.save
             flash[:success] = "Question saved successfully"
                redirect_to questions_url, notice: "Sucessfully created question"
       else
                render :new 
            end    
   
        end
   
        private
   
        def question_params
            params.require(:mc_question).permit(:question, :option1, :option2, :option3, :option4, :answer)
   
       end
    # def result
    #     @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    #     @question.update(result_params) # not sure this is best way here, need to research a better way to create the nested resources rather than update
    #    end
     
    #    private
    #      def result_params
    #        params.require(:result).permit(result_attributes: [:user_choice, :question_id, :user_id])
    #      end
    
end
```

**My result controller:**

class ResultController < ApplicationController

```
    def create
            @result=Result.create(user_choice: params[:user_choice], 
            question_id: params[:question_id], 
            user_id: current_user.id)
    end
    
end
```

**My index for question and storing user_choice:**

```
<div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
    <div class="card-body ">
       <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
      <div class="row py-5">
          <div class="p-5">
          <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 ">Multiple-Choice Questions</h1>
        </div>

     
    <%= form_with model: @result ,url: result_path do |f| %>
      <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= f.fields_for @questions do |fa|%>   # with this i get nothing no error and no save
    <%= fa.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
    <%end%>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        

        <p><%= question.question %></p>
        
        <% choices = [question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4] %>
        <% choices.each do |c| %>
            <div>
                <%= f.radio_button :"user_choice[#{question.id}]", c %>
                <%= f.label :user_choice, c  %>
            </div>
                <%end%>
            
        <% end %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
       
       <div class="sub"> <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>

<div class="para1"><%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path,class:"btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

**With this**

with this i get save everything but question id comes the last question id for every choice like if i have 12 questions then 12 will come for each choice

```
<%= fa.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
    <%end%>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

I want a different id for each choice please help me if anyone knows what's the issue and how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The reason you have that is because you have placed `<%= fa.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>` inside of this loop `<%= f.fields_for @questions do |fa|%>`  and it will populate using only one instance of your parent loop. Sort of like `for i in 0...12 for j in 0...13` for every i instance, the j loop will run 13 times.

Long story short, do this

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>   
  <%= fa.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <p><%= question.question %></p>
  <% choices = [question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, 
  question.option4] %> 
  <% choices.each do |c| %>
  <div>
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: I have did this but it store only the question id of last question and i need question id of each and every question

Comment: That’s odd. That code snippet should loop correctly please look at it very well

Comment: No it's only store the id of last i am looking into it from yesterday and i am completely stuck here

Comment: Please check i have updated the question with pgadmin pic

Comment: Please load the page and use developer tools to inspect each question element.

Comment: The question id of each question is ok it's the same that is coming from DB related to a question but i want to store question id of all the selected questions on submit button